# Can I Disable the Creation and Storage of LSO or Flash Cookie By Disable Adobe Flash Player?

Tags: flash, cookies, flash-cs5, lso

Can I Disable the Creation and Storage of LSO or Flash Cookie By Disable Adobe Flash Player?

Since it's a flash, I can just disable adobe flash player and it's all gone right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your capitalization... is "Cookie By Disable" some sort of a brand name?

Anyways. LSO files are saved in a certain place on your computer. Every instance of the player, standalone, a browser plugin or an ActiveX will save them in the same place. They have different function from web cookies, and you cannot disable them for the same reason you cannot disable a file... (it's not a function of a file, file is just data, you can't disable data, however, you can delete it).

When it comes to disabling anything related to these files, then your options are:

- Prevent automatic access (I'm guessing this is what you are after). As in preventing the player from accessing the files. You can do it in several different ways. The simplest is to [locate the directory, where the files are saved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object#File_locations) and set the access rules to disallow reading / writing for the user of Flash Player. This is also possible to do with some GUI help here: [www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html) . However this may break some Flash application which assume local storage accessibility.
- You may simply delete the files, it does no harm to any version or instance of Flash Plyaer.
- Disabling browser plugins will not remove the files, neither it will restrict any other programs from reading from the files. Because LSO does not serve the same purpose as cookies, there's no concept of expiration of the data stored, neither there is a concept of privacy. The data stored is unencrypted, unless the storing program specifically encrypts it. So, if you meant disabling as in making them impossible to read by other programs (rampaging in your PC :) with super-user access), then you could actually employ a mechanism similar to the encryption of regular cookies, or, rather any bidirectional encryption based on public / private keys. I.e. if your site stores cookies on a user machine and you are afraid that other programs on user machine may discover valuable information you stored there on behalf of the user, it would be wise to have a public key given to the user at authentication, which the program will then use to decrypt the local storage data.

Comment: So I need to delete the file and disable the plugin altogether?

Comment: So website can still store and read LSO on my computer even if I don't have adobe flash installed?

Comment: Then What if I disable every plugins in firefox.

Will They Still be Able to see the LSO then? Or The Native Firefox Without Plugins can Still Create and Read LSO?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/disable-third-party-local-shared.html

Seems a little bit outdated though…

Personally, I got a cursor and two checkboxes. I set the cursor to allow 0K to be stored and unchecked, at least, the first checkbox to disallow flash content to put stuff on your computer.

Note that you can no longer delete the default LSO called `settings.sol` as it stores the setting you just did. Deleting it undo what you just did.